# Why spring boot does not load beans configuration in order?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When i try to run a spring boot project, it tolde me that it can not autowire some beans whitch are instanciated in a configuration classes.
I think that spring can not load those configuration classes in order.

The stack trace : `no bean found the be autowired  Ignite<Long,MyEntity> myEntityCache in MyDao`

Here is  the source :

**The main class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
// The beans in the IgniteConfig have to be loaded before dao, service, and Controller
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={IgniteConfig.class,AppConfig.class})
public class DemoIgnite {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(DemoIgnite .class, args);
   }
}
```

**Config Class 1**

```
@Configuration
public class IgniteConfig {
@Bean
public SpringContext springContext() {
    return new SpringContext();
}

@Bean
public Ignite igniteInstance(@Autowired SpringContext springContext) {
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("instance");
List<CacheConfiguration> ccDas = new ArrayList<>();
CacheConfiguration cch = new CacheConfiguration<>("myEntitycache");
cch.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
cch.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, myEntity.class);
ccDas.add(cch);
cfg.setCacheConfiguration( ccDas.toArray(new CacheConfiguration[0]));
SpringCacheManager springCacheManager = new SpringCacheManager();
springCacheManager.setConfiguration(cfg);
return Ignition.start(cfg);


}

@Bean
public IgniteCache<Long, MyEntity> myEntityCache(@Autowired Ignite igniteInstance) {
 return igniteInstance.cache("myEntitycache");
}
```

**Config class 2**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({
"com.demo.repository",
"com.demo.service",
"com.demo.controller"
})
public class AppConfig {
}
```

**Dao class**

```
@Repository
public class MyDao{

@Autowired
private Ignite<Long,MyEntity> myEntityCache;
...
```

**Service class:**

```
@Service
public class MyService{

@Autowird
private MyDao dao;
...
```

**Controller class:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class MyController{

@Autowired
private MyService service;
....
```

Comment: Instead of taking them as a parameter, try callling igniteInstance() in myEntityCache(), and remove the parameter from igniteInstance() (as it doesn't seem to need the SpringContext for anything..  Spring usually finds all possible beans first, before creating any - so order of declaration should not matter... (I think that, as long as you have no cycles, it will order them as needed...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you don't have a bean of `Ignite<Long,MyEntity>` type in your context. Moreover `springContext` bean seems redundant, it's not used by `igniteInstance` bean. As pointed out by [moilejter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53254191/why-spring-boot-does-not-load-beans-configuration-in-order/53254310#comment93393225_53254310) it probably should be:

**IgniteConfig**

```
@Bean
public Ignite ignite() {
  ...
}

@Bean
public IgniteCache<Long, MyEntity> myEntityCache() {
  return ignite().cache("myEntitycache");
}
```

**MyDao**

```
@Repository
public class MyDao {

  @Autowired
  private IgniteCache<Long, MyEntity> myEntityCache;

  ...
}
```

In principle Spring performs the bean setup in few phases as explained in chapter [1.3.2. Instantiating Beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-class) docs:

1. Bean definition discovery - resources like `@Configuration` classes or `XML` files are scanned and bean signatures are collected.
2. Eager beans instantiation e.g. singletons - from the definitions collected in point 1 while resolving dependencies between definitions. That's why there is no explicit bean instantiation order as the process is driven from dependencies.
3. Lazy beans instantiation e.g. `@Lazy` annotated - when the context is already up, this beans will be constructed only when accessed from code.

Comment: I think this is right - the client is asking for a `Ignite<Long,MyEntity>` but the configuration defines a `IgniteCache<Long, MyEntity>` - which seems like a different type ...

Comment: @Karol Dowbecki: I still have the same exception : Field myEntityCache com.demo.dao.MyDao required a bean of type 'org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache' that could not be found.
And if i comment the dependency of IgniteCache in MyDao.class, Spring start and load it.
So let say that the configuration of IgniteConfig.class must be loaded in the first then Appconfig.class can be loaded

Comment: I made a mistake: In my Dao :private Ignite<String,MyEntity> myEntityCache; but in the configuration class i hade private Ignite<Long,MyEntity> myEntityCache; so not the same type (String vs Long) and that's why spring can't find the Bean igniteCache<String,...>
Problem resolved